# How can i get CSGO item details by Asset ID with Web API

Tags: json, steam, steam-web-api

I want to get any Steam or CSGO item details.

This details is Float Value and if is have a stickers it's.

I known it's have a web api for this.

I was do it but now i can't find this api url.

API was is returning JSON output.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There is no API endpoint to retrieve item information from an item's asset ID, because asset IDs are not universally unique. Asset IDs are only unique within a given context of a given user's inventory. The closest thing available is the `/ISteamEconomy/GetAssetClassInfo/v1` endpoint which provides information about attached stickers but not the specific float. If you have a user's steam ID, you can fetch the user's full inventory and get the specific float value from there.